# PhoneGap CRUD examples

Tags: iphone, sql, xcode, html, cordova

Im new to iPhone development and I find PhoneGap suitable for me for i am a web developer. I'm into practicing database using SQL. because of HTML5 support built into safari browser they support database natively into the browser.

I wonder if theres a good example that is easy to follow of using CRUD into SQL database in iPhone.

Comment: Is using PhoneGap mandatory for you? I recommend you Ruby on Rais, very very easy to develop and powerful too.

Comment: @ender WTF? PhoneGap is for making mobile apps for use on phones. Ruby on Rails doesn't run on a phone.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand either the question or read the description of PhoneGap carefully, I thought it was a framework for building web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your question, I think some points need to be explain:

## phonegap

Official documentation & description can be found on : [OfficialWebSite](http://www.phonegap.com/)

Phonegap is an open source framework / tool to develop cross mobile application. It allows to create mobile applications using only web technologies like html, css, javascript (ajax philosophy mostly used) and get access to APIs & app store. 
It provides a wrapper for javascript to access to core mobile technologies like sensor or gps...

You write your web application with phonegap functionnality, and after compilation for each plateform you obtain an native application (webview inside the application runs the application...)

To write the application, you can take advantage of HTML 5, javasvript

The obtained app can be deployed on the application store.

***actual supported plateform*** iPhone, Android, Blackberry, webOS, Symbian and Bada

## html5 & storage

One of the functionnality introduced by html 5 is the local storage which permits to manage local storage in your browser with a key-value approach. it could be considered as a super cookie (too much resteictive) and permits to speed up treatment or have an off line access to the application.

[Refence](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/)

[good introduction](http://sixrevisions.com/html/introduction-web-storage/)

***for example:***

- you can write a rss reader which download the news locally and store them tx to local storage. next lanch you just have to do the rotation with old news and if phone is out of network it works always but no update...

## CRUD

the html 5 storage could be manipulated with javascript

[manipulation sample](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html#methods)